# Set null values to a default in Postgresql case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'm trying to set a default value when my attribute comes up null in the database:

```
case categories.rental_price_percentage when null then '15.0' else categories.rental_price_percentage end rental
```

However, the replacement value isn't taking hold when I hit a null value (the rest is working though), it only displays null:

```
{
 id: "3",
 category_name: "Chairs",
 rental: null
}
```

How can I get the default value in and working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHEN NULL` in a simple `CASE` expression (it's not a statement) will never match because that would require, in your case, `categories.rental_price_percentage = NULL` to be true. But the result of comparison operations like `=`, `>`, ... against `NULL`s are `NULL` i.e. not true -- on only one or both sides, so even `NULL = NULL` is not true.

To check if an expression evaluates to `NULL` `IS NULL` is used.

So you could use a searched `CASE` expression:

```
CASE
  WHEN categories.rental_price_percentage IS NULL THEN
    15.0
  ELSE
    categories.rental_price_percentage
END rental
```

But replacing `NULL`s is such a common task, that there exists a function to do that, `coalesce()`. It returns the first of the arguments it gets passed, that is not `NULL`.

So in your case you could simply use:

```
coalesce(categories.rental_price_percentage, 15.0) rental
```

Note that I also removed the single quotes around `15.0` as it's presumably meant as a numeric value, not a string.

Comment: What if I need it to remain in the case expression? I have the `else` set up because the user is able to change the value from default; for instance, I could set it to 50% in the settings, and the value will render fine.

Comment: @Boucherie: So? You can change it in the `coalesce()` call too.

Comment: Do I have to change the whole structure of the expression? Please keep in mind that I normally work in ActiveRecord and am a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: @Boucherie: The question was about SQL. I don't know about ActiveRecord but since you apparently can inject raw SQL, as you did with your `CASE` expression, you can do the same with the `coalesce()`. Unless there's probably an ActiveRecord way of doing this. But that would be another question then.

Comment: Understood, I was only trying to convey that I needed a bit more explanation to your last comment.

Comment: @Boucherie: I think it's worth a try to replace the SQL text fragment you posted in your code with the `coalesce(...)...` an possibly replace the `15.0` in there with the value your user gave. If that was the link you're missing.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I replaced a section when I first tried it, didn't realize how versatile coalesce() actually was. Sorry about that, and thanks!